# Как работать с базой данных в android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-sqlite, xamarin.forms

Мне привычно работать с **СУБД** **MS SQL Server** и просматривать, создавать там таблицы, БД, связи. 
Начал знакомиться с мобильной разработкой, в проектах Xamarin есть возможность создавать БД и изменять в ней данные с помощью **EntityFramework.Core** для **S*QL Lite***.
А если я хочу сначала спроектировать базу данных, создать связи, таблицы и т.п - это возможно на устройстве android? Или как хотя бы посмотреть уже существующую БД, созданную EntityFramework'ом? мне нужно будет сделать схемы сущностей, связей и делать скриншоты, но не пойму как это делать. Мб есть материал по этой теме
Есть ли средства, предоставляющие подобный интерфейс?[image]
[image]

Comment: `мне нужно будет сделать схемы сущностей, связей` ==> Entity Framework Core Code First

Comment: `посмотреть уже существующую БД` SQLite бд - это просто файл, найти чем его открыть это [дело 10 секунд](https://www.google.com/search?&q=sqlite+viewer)

Comment: в коммерческой версии IntelliJ IDEA есть довольно мощный инструмент по работе с БД sqlite, что является наиболее удобным решением, так как вы имеете полный доступ к БД в процессе работы над приложением . Лично я подготавливаю БД на PC, под винду большое количество менеджеров баз данных, затем в приложении копирую готовую базу. Так же есть менеджеры SQLite и под Android, например SQLite editor

Comment: Спасибо, т. е проводником можно бд перемещать, верно? Отлаживаю на физическом устройстве

Answer (score 0):

Всеравно я не понимаю, как найти ту самую базу данных, которую создал EntityFramework. В проводнике искал, не нашёл, в папках проекта её, конечно же, нету. По этому пути тоже нет(Это путь для EF)[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Как её найти? Хотелось бы сохранить удобность обращения с бд с помощью entity framework, и при этом же видеть и трогать бд как локальную.. Есть информация?
Если начинаю дальше думать, если создавать БД как-то иначе, не через EF Code First, то как потом с помощью Entity с ней работать? Не укладывается в голове